# Unable to execute dex error in metaio imported project

Tags: eclipse, metaio

i created a simple app with a single tracker and simple object an exported as sdk. now I.ve imported the project into eclipse but it shows the following error:

*Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/metaio/BuildConfig;*

what could be the solution?

the initial error was unable to find .apk file, so i found a solution on internet which was to uncheck "is liabrary" from project property.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem while importing **metaio SDK module** into my Android project.

Here is the answer: Metaio SDK has a class `com.metaio.BuildConfig`. When the library project is built with Android build tool, it automatically created a class with the same name `"com.metaio.BuildConfig"`. Hence the class indeed is being defined twice!

So my solution is to rename the package name in the `AndroidMenifest.xml` of the metaio SDK module / project to something else like `"com.metaiosdk"`. After that, the app builds & runs smoothly.